# Two divs not positioning side-by-side using display: inline-block

Tags: css, html

I've just recently asked this and it worked previously but now it doesn't again. I have 2 divs (student-parent-container and student-guardian-other-container) I want positioned side-by-side using inline: block and if possible without using float.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="parent-and-guardian" class="tab">
    <div id="student-parent-guardian-container">
        <div id="student-parent-container">
            <fieldset id="student-father-info">
                <legend class="form-legend">Father Information</legend>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Contact No.:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label form-label-textarea">Address:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-input-textarea form-input-long"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Occupation:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="student-mother-info">
                <legend class="form-legend">Mother Information</legend>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Contact No.:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label form-label-textarea">Address:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-input-textarea form-input-long"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Occupation:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="student-guardian-other-container">
            <fieldset id="student-guardian-info">
                <legend class="form-legend">Guardian Information</legend>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Relation:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label">Contact No.:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-input form-input-long">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="form-label form-label-textarea">Address:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-input-textarea form-input-long"></textarea>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is CSS:

```
#student-parent-container
    display: inline-block;
}

#student-guardian-other-container
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a link to a jsFiddle:

[Divs not positioning side-by-side](https://jsfiddle.net/7x8xde43/)

I would like for Guardian Information be on the right side of Father Information.

Comment: have you tried float left ?

Comment: Because you are missing an opening curly brace for both of your CSS blocks: https://jsfiddle.net/7x8xde43/1/ - hence your CSS is invalid and none of your styles are applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't open the { in the css rules.

CSS

```
#student-parent-container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#student-guardian-other-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I updated your JS Fiddle, also adding a vertical-align to the guardian div:

https://jsfiddle.net/LinoLinux/7x8xde43/2/

Comment: I could've sworn that had an opening bracket... Anyway, thank you, I am missing obvious things, maybe I need to take a rest.